# AWS chalice how to reduce lamda deployment size

Tags: amazon-web-services, chalice

I have managed to deploy one lambda function fine with [chalice](https://chalice.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and the lambda function code was only like 15kb, I'm trying to do it again and this time it is over 8mb! I assume it is uploading my virtualenvironment too? How do I stop this happening and keep my code light enough to edit inline on the aws console?

Answer (score 0):

Bit of an awkward work around but I removed all contents from "requirements.txt" I then uploaded all my dependencies manually through lambda layers